# Find the Matrix of a Linear Transformation Relative to a Basis

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Our book gives this problem:

> Find the $\mathcal{B}$-matrix for the transformation $\vec{x} \rightarrow A\vec{x}$ when the basis $\mathcal{B} = \{ \vec{b}_1, \vec{b}_2 \}$, where $A = \left[\begin{array}{cc}
> 3 & 4 \\
> -1 & -1 \\
> \end{array} \right]$, $\vec{b}_1 = \left[\begin{array}{cc}
> 2 \\
> -1 \\
> \end{array} \right]$, and $\vec{b}_2 = \left[\begin{array}{cc}
> 1 \\
> 2 \\
> \end{array} \right]$.

From what I understand, it's asking us to find the matrix for the same exact transformation as $A$, except relative to to the given bases. I can't figure out where to go from here, though... any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need to do is form the matrix $B = (\vec{b}_1|\vec{b}_2)$, where $\vec{b}_i$ is the $i$th column of B, and note that this matrix converts vectors from the standard basis into the basis $\mathcal{B}$, while the inverse $B^{-1}$ will convert vectors in the basis $\mathcal{B}$ into the standard basis. Thus if you have a vector already in the basis $\mathcal{B}$, you can convert it to standard basis by multiplying by $B^{-1}$, multiply it by $A$, and finally convert back to $\mathcal{B}$ by multiplying by $B$, so your overall matrix is $BAB^{-1}$.

Comment: OHHHHH that's so easy! Just change coordinates, transform, and go back... wow. Thanks so much for the beautiful explanation! :)

Comment: Are you confident it's not $B^{-1}AB$? I'm convinced that it is. See 14:00 @ https://www.khanacademy.org/math/linear-algebra/alternate-bases/change-of-basis/v/lin-alg-transformation-matrix-with-respect-to-a-basis

Comment: @MaxLi Indeed it is. What they should have said is that the matrix $B$ converts the *components* of a vector in the $\mathcal B$ basis to its *components* in the standard basis. We want a matrix that transforms the components of $\vec x$ in the $\mathcal B$ basis to the components of $A\vec x$ in the $\mathcal B$ basis, so we need $B^{-1}AB$ (convert the components from $\mathcal B$ to standard, apply the transformation from standard to standard, and then convert back to $\mathcal B$).